# factor the expression completely $x^{-0.5}(x+1)^{0.5}+x^{0.5}(x+1)^{-0.5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Factor $x^{-0.5}(x+1)^{0.5}+x^{0.5}(x+1)^{-0.5}$.

I got $\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}$ but the answer is incorrect.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I got a common denominator and added straight through. I was not able to factor

Comment: It actually is correct. Perhaps someone further simplified (or complicated) it. Show what answer you have, which you think is different from your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct I also solve it a while ago, maybe you forgot to rationalize the denominator.

To do that multiply $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}$ in your answer.